# Multiple Clusters in one map

Tags: mapbox

I am currently using MapBox Cluster Example - https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/

I would like to use multiple GeoJSON and to cluster my annotations.

My problem is that if I add multiple GeoJSONs, the clusters are shown overlapped on top of each other. Instead of having 2/3 clusters it should only show 1 for that specific area.

Is there a way to only show one cluster?

I am using Swift but have left this out to see if anyone has had experience in Java etc.

Thanks